# Java Derby Create Database with dotted username

Tags: java, derby, javadb

I can not create database with below `connectionUrl`;

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:derby:myDB;create=true;user="+"john.smith"+";password="+"johnpassword"+";";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
java.sql.Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
```

When i use `johnsmith` for username it is successfully created. I suspect the dots are causing a problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must put double quotes around the user=john.smith ( symbol " needs to be escaped with \ in java), because it(Dot) is not a valid ordinary Identifier.

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:derby:myDB;create=true;user="+"\"john.smith\""+";password="+"johnpassword"+";";
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is work for me. But i did not know yet created user actually `john.smith` in DB or `"john.smith"` in DB. I have not tested yet.